# Had an update to PHP and php-fpm is handling all requests for logins. Phpmyadmin login is stuck in a loop

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Up until this php update to 8.0.10-2 phpmyadmin was working fine at the login screen. I am running CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105. Phpmyadmin 5.1.0.

in the /var/log/php-fpm directory the following 2 lines show up when I try to login with phpmyadmin:

> - -  26/Aug/2021:15:22:54 -0400 "GET /phpmyadmin/index.php" 200 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php 5.503 2048 0.00%
> - -  26/Aug/2021:15:23:00 -0400 "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/" 200 /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php 4.960 2048 201.61%

In the /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log I get the following line.

> 26-Aug-2021 19:25:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: POST Content-Length of 141 bytes exceeds the limit of 4 bytes in Unknown on line 0

The following 2 lines appear in the httpd/access.log file when I try to login in phpmyadmin:

> 108.59.215.125 - - [26/Aug/2021:15:27:34 -0400] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
> 108.59.215.125 - - [26/Aug/2021:15:27:38 -0400] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4585 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"

Other than that one error I can see, I can find no other errors or even redirects. Has anyone come across this issue, and may have some insight as to what to look for?

Comment: `POST Content-Length of 141 bytes exceeds the limit of 4 bytes` looks like your `post_max_size` is severely wrong -- 4 instead of 4G

Comment: MASSIVE THANKS!!!!  I had post_max_size=4GB.  Took off the "B" and other errors popped up.  Fixed those and things are working now!